# Normalization steps 2 and 3

Tags: normalization, database-normalization

Given the relation `Company(CompanyRefNumber,Name,City,Country,Turnover,Year)`.

For achieving 1st normal form, the composite attribute Location has been decomposed into City and Country.

Given that a company can have several locations, what do you propose for the next decomposition step and also finalise the decomposition to achieve 3rd normal form.

**My Attempt**

*Next decomposition step*

Company(CompanyRefNumber,Name,Turnover,Year)
Company(CompanyRefNumber,City,Country)

*Third Normal Form*

Company(CompanyRefNumber,Name,Turnover,Year)

Company(CompanyRefNumber,City)

Company(CompanyRefNumber,Country)

Comment: Your last version is wrong, because you can't tell which city is in which country.

Comment: Just because the normal forms are numbered, it is not true that one should move through them in order. Anyway, normalization to 3NF requires identifying functional dependencies, then candidate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
    ah oh
      |
      v  
--------------------------------------          
1, Google, Mountain View, US, 1B, 2014
1, Google, Seattle, US, 10M, 2014
1, Google, London, UK, 50M, 2013
2, Bloomberg, New York, US, 100M, 2014
2, Bloomberg, New York, US, 90M, 2013
```

There is a primary key`(CompanyRefNumber, City, Country, Year)` which uniquely identifies each record.

However, we find company `Name` only depends on `CompanyRefNumber` which does not comply to 2nd Normal Form that **non-primary key cannot depend on any subset of primary key**.

To normalize, we can create a new relationship `CompanyInfo` as below:

```
--------------------------------------
1, Google
2, Bloomberg
```

At this point, non-primary attribute is only `turnover`, and obviously there is no other non-primary attribute out there to determine the value of `turnover`, and thus comply to 3rd Normal Form that **non-primary key cannot depend on any other non-primary key** by nature.